# Name for an almost diagonal real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

If $A$ is a real square matrix which is diagonalisable over the complex numbers, then it is conjugate (over the reals) with a matrix $D$ which is block-diagonal, where each block on the diagonal is either a single real, or a scalar multiple of a $2\times 2$ rotation matrix.

Is there a common name for a matrix such as $D$? In relation to $A$, I would call it a real Jordan normal form (slightly degenerate, since $A$ diagonalises over $\mathbf C$), but I was wondering if there is a name for this form as an intrinsic property.

Comment: I think that the name  "block-diagonal" is not bad, and certainly better than "almost diagonal" from your title.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: It's not bad, but it's more general. I mean the blocks to have a very specific form. And I'm not saying the one in the title is good, the whole point is that I want a good one.

Comment: I only know the name block matrix, or real canonical form, with single real blocks or scalar multiples of rotation matrices of size two. In which text did they arise?

Comment: @DietrichBurde They did not arise in any text. I'm editing some lecture notes of mine for a linear algebra course and I wanted to include the spectral theorem for normal operators on an Euclidean space (as a simple corollary of the spectral for normal operators on a unitary space) where such matrices would arise. I haven't seen it in any textbook, but I felt like including it in an appendix for completeness. Real canonical form can have identities off-diagonal. I do include that as well, but in the spectral theorem you can get rid of the off-diagonal terms (and you have an ON basis).